# JSTL & Javascript

Tags: javascript, jstl, iteration

I am using JSTL `forEach` to loop and structure a table. The difficulty I am having is I need to process that data with Javascript functions before shown to the user. Is there a way/syntax to call a Javascript function(s) after JSTL has rendered the tag, but before it loops again?  If not, is there a way with JSTL or Struts iteration to uniquely and serially tag the `<td/>` elements with a `row:col` ID, so I can later process them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way/syntax to call a Javascript function(s) after JSTl has rendered the tag, but before it loops again?

Obviously not: JSTL processing is happening on the server side. JS happens after the JSP is completely rendered and delivered to the client.

> If not, is there a way with JSTL or Struts iteration to uniquely and serially tag the elements with a row:col ID, so I can later process them?

Of course, you can put whatever you want into DOM `id` and/or `class` attributes, or use things like `data-id`/etc. attributes if you want to keep that information separate.

The best approach depends on what specifically you're doing, though.